# Migrate Existing project to Spring Boot MVC multi Dispatcher from JSP, Servlet, etc

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot, jersey

I need to convert old project to Spring Boot and MVC.
In old version used technologies are- JSP, Servlet, Hibernate, JPA, Jersey

I need help to do all of this with minimal effort.

1. How can I convert `web.xml` to `SpringBoot Configauration`, problem is that- MVC also have a `dispatcher`.

```html
         <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

2. How can I do this with minimal code changes?

   ```
   @Path("/aaccess")
   public class RestAAccess {
   @GET
   @Path("/get/{id}")
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   public Object get(@PathParam("id") int id) {
       //
   }

   @POST
   @Path("/doit")
   @Produces("application/json")
   public Object doit(@FormParam("id") int id,
                      @FormParam("role_id") int rid,
                      @FormParam("action") String action,
                      @FormParam("granted") boolean granted,
                      @FormParam("act") String act) {
       //
   }
   ```

   }
3. Existing Dao-Implementation Class (without interface). How to change this

   ```
   public class CStaffData {
       public static List<CStaffResult> getByCompany(Session se, ResultPack rp, int id) {
          // --
               List<CStaffResult> table = se.createQuery("Some SQL").setParameter("id", id).setResultTransformer(Transformers.TO_LIST).list();
          //---    
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: __Consider splitting this in 3 individual questions:__ Each of them is valuable content for our knowledge database. Each of them should have a different tilte to attract people having the same problem in the future. _(And you might gain reputation point from each too!)_

Comment: Thanks you Dirk, for valuable advice. But I think answers may complex and related each others. In your case, have possibility solution one problem can conflict others.

Answer (score 1):

1: put `server.contextPath=/webapi` in application.properties

```
2:  
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/aaccess")
    public class RestAAccess {

    @RequestMapping(value="/get/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object get(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        //
    }

    @RequestMapping(value=""/doit"",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object doit(@RequestBody SampleBody sb) {
        //
    }

class SampleBody{

         int id,

         @JsonProperty(value = "role_id")int rid,

         @JsonProperty("action") String action;

         @JsonProperty("granted") boolean granted;

         @JsonProperty("act") String act;

      ...........getter setters ......
 }
```

3: Better Use Respository or Dao properly check spring docs.

Comment: Problem 1 - there also have MVC dispatcher and I use it for JSP. I mean, all JSP pages goes through controller and show without extension. In your case all project will start  from /webapi/*
Problem 2 - I need using existing annotations without changing, if its possible.
Problem 3 - I will explain details, there existing code with Session parameter. In Sring Boot Session is not exist or its exist in backgound. 
I'm also researching find solution myself, if will find I will inform solution.

Comment: I find resource and seems it is possible to use existing annotations -https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-building-restful-web-services-with-jersey

Comment: 1: yes, if you change context path it will change for all request, you can start   all api root resource path with "webapi", My solution was as per your code snippet. for 2,3 why you are switching to spring ecosystem if you are going to keep all the code same

Answer (score 1):

I find solution for my problem.

First and second problem I read from here:
http://www.gauravbytes.com/2017/02/spring-boot-restful-webservices-with.html

Add this part to pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This part is not needed if you already using tomcat embed. Together will not work, just for information.

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

About this you can read here (9th point):
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-application-configuration

After thats using Jersey annotations you need just add `@Component` annotation.

Also you must add for register jersey dispatcher:

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
  public JerseyConfiguration() {

  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void setUp() {
    register(RestAAccess.class);
  }
}
```

If old project exist another servlets, you also can add using below code:    x`
(Read here - http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/servlet-component-beans/)

Servlet class:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.println("response from servlet ");
    }
}
```

Congiguration function (add your main class):

```
@Bean
ServletRegistrationBean myServletRegistration () {
    ServletRegistrationBean srb = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    srb.setServlet(new MyServlet());
    srb.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("/path2/*"));
    return srb;
}
```

About SessionFactory solution not ready (not tested). In case, I will add future.